# What's the difference between rand() and mt_rand(), as of PHP 5.4?

Tags: php

According to the official document, mt_rand() should be four time faster than rand().

But after I read [this article](http://en.code-bude.net/2013/01/06/php-rand-vs-mt_rand-what-is-more-accurate-what-is-faster/) which claims that there is no noticeable difference between the two, I [tried this on Google App Engine](http://cqdphptest.appspot.com/rand/index.html)(which is PHP 5.4). The result is almost identical.

So, what's the difference between rand() and mt_rand() for PHP 5.4 and after? How do I determin which one to use?

Comment: Some say that `mt_rand()` is a bit faster. You'd have to read up on both functions to compare.

Comment: 30 sec. Google find: http://tjl.co/blog/code/followup-php-rand-vs-mt_rand/ and http://en.code-bude.net/2013/01/06/php-rand-vs-mt_rand-what-is-more-accurate-what-is-faster/ and http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/4/6/2

Answer (score 1):

Four times faster than a blink is still a blink. Specially considering it's a built-in function in an interpreted language, performance shouldn't be it's most distinctive characteristic.

According to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php):

> > By default, PHP uses the libc random number generator with the rand() function. The mt_rand() function is a drop-in replacement for this. **It uses a random number generator with known characteristics** using the [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister), which will produce random numbers four times faster than what the average libc rand() provides.

Answer (score 0):

With the `mt_rand()` you can generate random numbers just like with the rand() function in php.`mt_rand()` will be a little more faster in my opinion..

Just have a read here..http://en.code-bude.net/2013/01/06/php-rand-vs-mt_rand-what-is-more-accurate-what-is-faster/

Comment: That is not what the page says. It says on Windows the `rand()` is unusable for most anything needing truer randomness bc it will produce numbers that are linearly dependent, so for everything you want to use `mt_rand()`.

Answer (score 0):

the difference is only the speed

see this to know more about it http://tjl.co/blog/code/followup-php-rand-vs-mt_rand/